# Correct use for Switch? Menu option order a Sandwich OR Salad

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

Good Morning/Afternoon,

Below is the code I've written for my Java class ( As in school homework ). I'm not here trying to get someone to do the homework for me.

My question is: Can the switch/case be used how I have it set?
Prompt user for input 1 or 2. Answer 1 they are getting a sandwich, answer 2 they are getting a salad.

The instructions for this program starts with the customer will order a ***sandwich*** or a ***salad***. Then proceed to add toppings for an additional charge and can decline extra toppings as well.Then print out the order and total. The professor specified to use IF statements and the Switch. However, I have a feeling I am missing something because it looks like the Switch is the replacement of the IF statements in the examples I've found on Stack. Thank you for any and all assistance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

//loaded scanner to take user input
public class Restaurant


//dude change this, do 3 outputs asking for input 1 input 2 input 3 make those if statements after
{
/* Author: 
   Date: 
   Program: create a class that will offer a sandwich for $7.00 with optional three 
   toppings lettuce, tomato, cheese $1.00 each
   or a salad  with optional two toppings tomatos, cheese $0.50 each.
*/   
   public static void main(String[] args)

   {

   // Declarations sandwich,salad,Sandwich-cheese,Sandwich-tomato,Sandwich-lettuce, salad-cheese, salad-tomato.
      double sandwich = 7.00;
      double salad = 7.00;
      double sandChe = 1.00;
      double sandTom = 1.00;
      double sandLet = 1.00;
      double salChe = .50;
      double salTom = .50;
      int userInput;
      int userInput1;
      int userInput2;
      int userInput3;
      double sandTotal;
      double saladTotal;

      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter 1 for a Sandwich or 2 for a Salad");
      int userInput = scanner.nextLine();

      switch(userInput)
      {
         case 1: // a sandwich was ordered




            System.out.println("Enter 1 for additional topping of lettuce or press 2");
            int userInput1 = scanner.nextLine();


            System.out.println("Enter 1 for additional topping of cheese or press 2");
            int userInput2 = scanner.nextLine();


            System.out.println("Enter 1 for additional topping of tomato or press 2");
            int userInput3 = scanner.nextLine();



            if (userInput1 == 1 && userInput2 == 1 && userInput3 == 1)
            {
               saladTotal = (sandwich + sandLet + sandChe + sandTom);
               System.out.println("Your bill comes to a total of: " + sandTotal + " Thank you, Have a great day!");



               if (userInput1 == 1 && userInput2 == 2 && userInput3 == 2)
               {
                  sandTotal = (sandwich + sandLet);
                  System.out.println("Your bill for a salad with additional tomato toppings comes too: " + sandTotal + " Thank you, Have a great day!");


                  if (userInput1 == 1 && userInput2 == 1 && userInput3 == 2)
                  {
                     sandTotal = (sandwich + sandLet + sandChe);
                     System.out.println("Your bill for a salad with no additional toppings comes too: " + salad + " Thank you, Have a great day!");


                     if (userInput1 == 1 && userInput2 == 2 && userInput3 == 1)
                     {
                        sandTotal = (sandwich + sandLet + sandTom );
                        System.out.println("Your bill for a sandwich `enter code here`lettuce and tomato comes too: " + sandTotal + " Thank you, Have a great day!");     


                        if (userInput1 == 2 && userInput2 == 1 && userInput == 1)
                        { 
                           sandTotal = (sandwich + sandChe + sandTom);
                           System.out.println("Your bill for a sandwich with cheese and tomato comes too: " + sandTotal + " Thank you, Have a great day!");


                           if (userInput1 == 2 && userInput2 == 2 && userInput3 == 2)
                           {
                              System.out.println("Your bill for a sandwich comes too: " + sandwich + " Thank you, Have a great day!");
                           }// end if 1
                        }//end if 2
                     }//end if 3
                  }//end if 4
               }//end if 5
            }//end if 6

      }
   }
}            


         // switch case below


         case 2: // a salad was ordered




            {
               System.out.println("Press 1 for additional topping of cheese or press 2");
               int userInput1 = scanner.nextLine();



               System.out.println("Press 1 for additional topping of tomato or press 2");
               int userInput2 = scanner.nextLine();


               if (userInput1 == 1 && userInput2 == 2)
               {
                  saladTotal = (salad + salChe);
                  System.out.println("Your bill comes to a total of: " + saladTotal + " Thank you, Have a great day!");



                  if (userInput1 == 2 && userInput2 == 1)
                  {
                     saladTotal = (salad + salTom);
                     System.out.println("Your bill for a salad with additional tomato toppings comes too: " + saladTotal + " Thank you, Have a great day!");


                     if (userInput1 == 2 && userInput2 == 2)
                     {
                        System.out.println("Your bill for a salad with no additional toppings comes too: " + salad + " Thank you, Have a great day!");


                        if (userInput1 == 1 && userInput2 == 1)

                        {
                           saladTotal = (salad + salChe + salTom );
                           System.out.println("Your bill for a salad with Tomato and Cheese toppings comes too: " + saladTotal + " Thank you, Have a great day!");

                        }//end if 1
                     }//end if 2
                  }//end if 3
               }//end if 4


            }



}// end of class
```

Comment: Did you test your code? Because if statements / code blocks don't work the way you think. Everything in the if statement (from `{` to `}`) will only happen if the condition is true, so none of the other if statements will ever run since those conditions can't all be true. Why did you nest them? Don't nest them. Just put them under each other (put the `}` **before** the next if statement, not right at the end).

Comment: Also, yes, that's an appropriate use of `switch`, but you can also just use an if statement instead if it's just the 2 conditions you're checking, and asking whether working code is the "correct use" is not really on topic for [so], since that's often going to come down to opinion, which is at odds with what [so] strives to be.

Comment: I don't see the `break;` after the first `switch` case so probably an error because of that, also try to change them instead of your nested `if` use a `switch` and replace your current `switch` with an `if`. This basically because an `if` is commonly used when few options whereas a `switch` when many

Comment: Duke- excellent point! obviously didn't think of that.. I was thinking the IF's were a whole entity. - Thank you!

Comment: As for the correct use, I didn't mean is this the only possibly way, I just meant I'm reading others using the Switch in a fashion that shows multiple answers. I didn't see any examples where the switch was used as a primary sort tool for the first user prompt. - Still well noted thanks!

Comment: 3vts- Thank you, my book said a break isn't necessary but in this situation I think you are correct. I will use the break; appreciate it! - you guys/gals are awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, switch-case statements and if/else blocks are interchangeable. Switch-cases are a bit different because of the use of `break` (an example below). Though in most cases if-statements are used. I generally use switch-case for handling cases based on enumerations.

Lets say we have an enumeration FoodType:

```
public enum FoodType {
    SANDWITCH,
    SALAD,
    FRUIT
}
```

So if i want to ask the user questions based on which food he chooses, I would probably do something like this:

```
FoodType chosenType = FoodType.SANDWITCH; // can be user input

switch (chosenType) {
case SANDWITCH:
    System.out.println("you want cheese?");
case SALAD:
    System.out.println("Sauce?");
    break;
case FRUIT:
    System.out.println("which one?");
    break;
default:
    throw new IllegalStateException();
}
```

Note here:

- When SANDWITCH is chosen, questions 'you want cheese?' and 'Sauce?' are printed, because there is no `break` statement.
- When FRUIT is chosen, only 'which one?' will be printed.
- `default` would happen, if the user chose somthing else, which is not SANDWITCH or SALAD or FRUIT.

You could of course write this with if statements as well:

```
if (FoodType.SALAD.equals(chosenType)) {...}
```

When there are few cases I would rater use simple if statements. Also, the code inside a 'case' should not be overly long/complicated. I think if you want to know when to use which statement; there are for sure some very good blog posts or stackoverflow answers.

*// Sidenote: I am aware that the `default:` is not be reachable code in the example.*

Comment: Great example and explanation! I believe my confusion revolves around the professor asking to use switch and if statements. If I use Switch the case"s" will be very long and complex ( at least for my skill set ). If I use the If statements this will give the desired results but omits use of the Switch unless I used for the first option which has a simple answer Sandwich or Salad. Thank you for your input!